# Which is link to the reference page of "?" (help) operator?

Tags: documentation

We can use `?` operator to find help reference pages for the command.

Which is link to the reference page of "?" (help) operator?

I tried:

```
??
```

But it does not gives me any result.

Comment: Use `?Information`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL@Information[Table]["Documentation"][ "Web"]
```

[image]

---

[image]